# What is the proper way to mention "current" for future events?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, adjectives

I am writing a software user manual so the topic is about possible situations which its users may come across.

Here is an example sentence:

> The button saves the **current** URL in the browser.

Usage of **current** above does not mention the present time actually, so what is the proper way to mention "current" for future events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster's Online Dictionary:

> 1 b (1) : presently elapsing <the current year> (2) : occurring in or existing at the present time <the current crisis> (3) : most recent <the magazine's current issue>

Two of these definitions mention *present:*

> 2 a : being in view or at hand
>   b : existing in something mentioned or under consideration

So using *current* is correct, as it always denotes whatever time the sentence refers to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the use of "current" is that ambiguous here, but if you do, you still can make your sentence more explicit:

> The button saves the current URL in the browser.
>   ("current" at the time when you will press said button)